# Add a column in Spark Dataset from other 2 column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `Dataset<Row>` in spark just like:

```
+----+-------+
| age|   name|
+----+-------+
|  15|Michael|
|  30|   Andy|
|  19| Justin|
+----+-------+
```

Now I want to add a column that has value of string value of `age` plus string value of `name`,like:

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| age|   name|cbdkey     |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  15|Michael|  15Michael|
|  30|   Andy|  30Andy   |
|  19| Justin|  19Justin |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

I use:

```
df.withColumn("cbdkey",col("age").+(col("name"))).show()
```

But all value of new column `cbdkey` is `null`. So,How should I do this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `concat` function:

```
df.withColumn("cbdkey", concat(col("age"), col("name"))).show
+---+-------+---------+
|age|   name|   cbdkey|
+---+-------+---------+
| 15|Michael|15Michael|
| 30|   Andy|   30Andy|
| 19| Justin| 19Justin|
+---+-------+---------+
```

If you need to specify a custom separator, use `concat_ws`:

```
df.withColumn("cbdkey", concat_ws(",", col("age"), col("name"))).show
+---+-------+----------+
|age|   name|    cbdkey|
+---+-------+----------+
| 15|Michael|15,Michael|
| 30|   Andy|   30,Andy|
| 19| Justin| 19,Justin|
+---+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks you, your answer works.

Answer (score 2):

Other way is to write a UDF (User Defined Function) call this on the dataframe

```
val concatUDF = udf {
  (age: Int, name: String) => {
    age + name
  }
}

df.withColumn("cbdkey", concatUDF(col("age"), col("name"))).show()
```

output:

```
+---+-------+---------+
|age|   name|   cbdkey|
+---+-------+---------+
| 15|Michael|15Michael|
| 30|   Andy|   30Andy|
| 19| Justin| 19Justin|
+---+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Not required here. Spark SQL supports `concat` and `concat_ws`